# How to retrieve multiple tweets from tweet_id using R

Tags: r, twitter

I am using the **twitteR** package in R to extract tweets based on their ids. 
But I am unable to do this for multiple tweet ids without hitting either a rate limit or an error 404.
This is because I am using the **showStatus()** - one tweet id at a time.
I am looking for a function similar to  **getStatuses()** - multiple tweet id/request

**Is there an efficient way to perform this action.**
I suppose only 60 requests can be made in a 15 minute window using the outh.

So, how do I ensure :-
1.**Retrieve multiple tweet ids for single request thereafter repeating these requests.**
2.**Rate limit is under check.**
3.**Error handling for tweets not found.**

P.S : This activity is not user based.

Thanks

Comment: I am still a bit confused about what you want. But, I have been using `streamR`. If you use `filterStream` you can collect tweets for the period of time you specify. You can specify a location if you want. Once you have all tweets are in, you use `parseTweets` which gives you a data frame. You can subset your data using userID. Presumably, if a user tweeted multiple times in the period of time, you have multiple tweets in the data frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have come across the same issue recently. For retrieving tweets in bulk, [Twitter recommends](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/lookup) using the `lookup`-method provided by its API. That way you can get up to 100 tweets per request.

Unfortunately, this has not been implemented in the `twitteR` package yet; so I've tried to hack together a quick function (by re-using lots of code from the `twitteR` package) to use that API method:

```
lookupStatus <- function (ids, ...){
  lapply(ids, twitteR:::check_id)

  batches <- split(ids, ceiling(seq_along(ids)/100))

  results <- lapply(batches, function(batch) {
    params <- parseIDs(batch)
    statuses <- twitteR:::twInterfaceObj$doAPICall(paste("statuses", "lookup", 
                                                         sep = "/"),
                                                   params = params, ...)
    twitteR:::import_statuses(statuses)
  })
  return(unlist(results))
}

parseIDs <- function(ids){
  id_list <- list()
  if (length(ids) > 0) {
    id_list$id <- paste(ids, collapse = ",")
  }
  return(id_list)
}
```

Make sure that your vector of `ids` is of class `character` (otherwise there can be a some problems with very large IDs).

Use the function like this:

```
ids <- c("432656548536401920", "332526548546401821")
tweets <- lookupStatus(ids, retryOnRateLimit=100)
```

Setting a high `retryOnRateLimit` ensures you get all your tweets, even if your vector of IDs has more than 18,000 entries ([100 IDs per request, 180 requests per 15-minute window](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/rate-limits)).

As usual, you can turn the tweets into a data frame with `twListToDF(tweets)`.

Comment: Hi Dave, thanks for this function... it is very useful!