# Grabbing Tweets from Multiple Timelines (twitteR "usertimeline" function)

Tags: r, twitter

I'm trying to grab the most recent tweets from multiple users. I have already had my application registered, and have the requisite keys and tokens.

I know that for a single user, the command is:

```
recent <- twListToDF(userTimeline("**twitterID**",n=15))
```

However, I'm unsure how to grab the Tweets for multiple IDs, and how to combine them into data frame.

I tried:

```
targets <- c("a","b","c")
recent <- twListToDF(userTimeline("targets",n=15))
```

where `a`, `b`, `c` are `IDs`, but get the error message:

> Error in twInterfaceObj$doAPICall(cmd, params, method, ...) :
>     Not Found (HTTP 404).

It doesn't seem to matter whether target is surrounded by quotes or not. Is there a simple way to grab tweets from multiple IDs? Or do I need to have a vector, iterate through etc.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2692434/php-twitter-api-how-to-pull-in-multiple-users-tweets That's for PHP but it might help you

Comment: Do the ids have incremental numbers or are they different,either way you can iterate through the list of those ids and run this command every time in a loop. you putting a list directly into your function thats why it is throwing error.

Comment: Also I think you should take a look at this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26645672/how-to-retrieve-multiple-tweets-from-tweet-id-using-r?rq=1

Comment: @ShwetaKamble, these are non incremental IDs. I am actually passing in their text usernames right as of now.

Comment: Try using lapply and pass the vector of IDs in the function to get your tweets,  please refer the above link to complete your code. Make sure to keep the ID vector as character.

Comment: @ShwetaKamble is there a method that doesn't require the numeric IDs, but could instead handle the usernames, either as a vector or list?

Comment: @ShwetaKamble, so I looked at the PHP solution, but it seems like with Twitter API 1.01 being deprecated, it no longer works. As you suggested, I have the screennames of the users whose Tweets I want in a vector, called `writerList`. I then use `DF <- lapply(writerList,getTweets)`, but receive an OAuth authentication error. When I try my getTweets function for a singular user, there is no such error. Thoughts?

Comment: Please look at this R code example for the same issue you are facing, I havent given a PHP link at all. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26645672/how-to-retrieve-multiple-tweets-from-tweet-id-using-r?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, so I thought I'd share my solution to the problem.

Assuming I have the same list of screen names to pull Tweets from, called `targets`.

I put the output into a list, called `output`, with each entry corresponding to the tweets from the same index value in `targets`. I.e., `output[1]` contains all the tweets from `targets[1]`, with one tweet on each line.

```
num = length(targets)
output <- vector("list", num)
for(i in 1:num){
  output[i] <- getTweets(targets[i])
}
```

getTweets uses `twListToDF(userTimeline(handle, n=15))`

---

To put all the Tweets into a single dataframe,complete with other info:

```
masterFrame <- data.frame()
for (i in 1:num){
  tempFrame <- getTweets(targets[i])
  masterFrame <- rbind(masterFrame, tempFrame)
}
```