# How to sort tweets returned by batch status ID in order as submitted by twitteR

Tags: r, twitter, batch-processing

I have a list of over 16K tweet ID's of which I would like to obtain the text. I am using twitteR and two functions [from this SO reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26645672/how-to-retrieve-multiple-tweets-from-tweet-id-using-r) that I am reproducing here:

```
library(twitteR)
library(ROAuth)
library(httr)

lookupStatus <- function (ids, ...){
  lapply(ids, twitteR:::check_id)
  batches <- split(ids, ceiling(seq_along(ids)/100))

  results <- lapply(batches, function(batch) {
    params <- parseIDs(batch)
    statuses <- twitteR:::twInterfaceObj$doAPICall(paste("statuses", "lookup", sep = "/"), params = params, ...)
    twitteR:::import_statuses(statuses)
   })
   return(unlist(results)) # does not return the tweets in the order they are submitted
}


parseIDs <- function(ids){
  id_list <- list()
  if (length(ids) > 0) {
    id_list$id <- paste(ids, collapse = ",")
  }
  return(id_list)
}

api_key <- CONSUMER_KEY
api_secret <- CONSUMER_SECRET
access_token <- OAUTH_TOKEN
access_token_secret <- OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET
setup_twitter_oauth(api_key, api_secret, access_token, access_token_secret)

tweetcsv <- data.frame(as.character(c(597576902212063232, 65586175864610817, 
563881580209246209, 595380689534656512, 563757610327748608, 
563082741370339330, 596962098845851648, 563874350038675457, 
597240424873394176, 571030421103910912)))
colnames(tweetcsv) <- c("tweetID")

activeIDs <- lookupStatus(tweetcsv$tweetID)
```

This is returning a list where I can access each element using `activeIDs$'11'` (I cannot understand why this has happened). I can also access each element's sub-elements using `activeIDs$'11'$` where there are a ton of features to choose from such as created, favoriteCount, favorited, id, isRetweet, text, id, etc. There are more than 70 of these fields.

What I would like to have the API return is just the tweet's text in the same order that the ID was submitted as in my original data I have four columns with the first one being the tweet ID whilst the rest are what a human decided for the tweet to be, 0ffenisve, sexism etc. So the order of the returned tweet text is important so that I can insert the text in the dataset.  The data I have is from [Hate speec Twitter annotations](https://github.com/ZeerakW/hatespeech) dataset. It would be great if I could get just the text and the ID from the API as it would save a few calls most probably. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.